# Check to see if Sheet exists in Excel and record result as Boolean

Tags: vb.net, excel, office-interop

I am learninf excel to vb.net connection from this site:
http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/09/09/checking-if-a-sheet-exists/

I am **trying to check if sheet exists** and **record result in boolean**.

```
    Dim SheetNameToCheck As String = "Sheet1"
    Dim xs As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sheet_found As Boolean
    '~~> Opens an exisiting Workbook. Change path and filename as applicable
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\...\myExcel2007file.xlsx")
    '~~> Display Excel
    xlApp.Visible = True
    '~~> Loop through the all the sheets in the workbook to find if name matches
    For Each xs In xlWorkBook.Sheets
        If xs.Name = SheetNameToCheck Then
            sheet_found = True
        Else
            sheet_found = False
        End If
    Next



    If sheet_found = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("The sheet " & SheetNameToCheck & " found.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Not found.")
    End If
```

The problem is that the result comes as Not Found whatever string you check with

The error comes in the For loop. 
First the loop checks excel Sheet1 to see if it meets the string to check which is "Sheet1". The variable sheet_found is obviously "True".

But when it goes to the next sheet, Sheet 2 and Sheet3 the result turns to false and I an unable to check if the sheet actually exists in the workbook.

Comment: When performing this kind of comparisons you might prefer to ignore caps and remove starting/ending blank spaces to make completely sure. For example: `If xs.Name.Trim().ToLower() = SheetNameToCheck.Trim().ToLower() Then`; but this is the maximum that I can correct from this code, it is fine. Just confirm that there is a worksheet called Sheet1 in the target file at all (what apparently is not the case).

Comment: PS: this is VB.NET, nothing to do with vba

Comment: Thank you for the answer
There is a sheet named "Sheet1" and I have debugged it step by step. The problem is not in recognizing if the sheet exists. It is in handling the code of vb.net. The result first comes as true, then as false and another false(For sheet 2 and 3)

Comment: Ah! sorry, just exit the loop (`Exit For` below `sheet_found = True`). Alternatively (someone might say that relying on Exit is a bad practice) you might set the loop such that it only runs until this condition is met: `While (Not sheet_found)` instead of `For each`.

Comment: Thank you. Post that answer as an original answer, I will select it. that solved it.

Comment: Thanks but I was doing something else. Anyway... when I write a comment, I usually prefer to let it as a comment (and seemed to be more interesting to Patrick anyway...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

under `sheet_found = True` should be an `Exit For` line before the `Else` statement, as varocarbas suggests

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to varocarbas and patrick for the answers. Here is the code that worked

```
 Dim SheetNameToCheck As String = "Sheet22"
    Dim xs As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sheet_found As Boolean
    '~~> Opens an exisiting Workbook. Change path and filename as applicable
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\...\myExcel2007file.xlsx")
    '~~> Display Excel
    xlApp.Visible = True
    '~~> Loop through the all the sheets in the workbook to find if name matches

    For Each xs In xlWorkBook.Sheets
        If xs.Name = SheetNameToCheck Then
            sheet_found = True
            Exit For
        Else
            sheet_found = False
        End If
    Next

    If sheet_found = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("The sheet " & SheetNameToCheck & " found.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Not found.")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with that else statement at the first place? Make it false as default, and only change it to true, if you find your sheet.

Comment: This is more a comment on the other answers than an answer that stands on its own. I'd recommend to [edit] it and show the code with the modification you suggest.